# Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm getting the error `"Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI"`. Request you provide the details to fix the issue.

I have set the below in the client side.

```
HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties();
proxyProperties.setProxyName(proxyAddress);
proxyProperties.setProxyPort(proxyPort);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED,Boolean.FALSE);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE,"application/soap+xml");
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty("type","application/soap+xml");
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.HEADER_SOAP_ACTION, Action_URL);
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty ( HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_11 ) ;
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty ( "Transfer-Encoding", "chunked" ) ;
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT, "true");
```

Can you please help to solve the issue?

Answer (score 21):

That error occurs if there is a mismatch between the content type and the SOAP version (as determined by the namespace URI of the SOAP envelope) of the received message. E.g. if Axis2 receives a SOAP 1.2 message with content type `text/xml`, it will trigger that error.

Comment: What should the Content-Type contain?  Should that header be removed from the request entirely?  Ah, here's the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465349/what-content-type-should-be-in-http-header-of-soap-1-2-message

Answer (score 0):

Joe - If you are getting this error, then I am assuming that you are trying to access a service that is really old and you might be using Axis that is version 2.0 . You will not be able to call the service by creating client using Axis or CXF. I have spent days trying to figure this out. Eventually I ended up using SAAJ API to create the request WSDL and post it to the service.

It is very easy and keeps you away from trying to figure out RPC/Literal/Document style etc.

See this post - [Post](http://www.javahabit.com/2014/10/17/quick-tutorial-saaj-api/)