# What content type should be in http header of soap 1.2 message?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap, zsi

I have a problem where my xml-da client that is using zsi 2.2.2 library generating messages that look like soap 1.2 messages because I can see this line.

```
xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
```

But I also can see text/xml as a content type in header. I can't find any notion of what header should be like in soap 1.2, but I suppose that it should be application/soap-xml.

So what it actually should be?

Comment: From the [SOAP 1.2 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/) (section 1.3): *"The media type `"application/soap+xml"` SHOULD be used for XML 1.0 serializations of the SOAP message infoset"*. See also [RFC 3902](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3902.txt).

Comment: There is a lot of soap specifications out there. I just felt lost in all of them. Are you sure that soap 1.2 message should always have a header with content type application/soap+xml?

Comment: Note that SOAP 1.1 requires `text/xml` as Content-Type.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Content-Type: application/soap+xml

Comment: I was testing an axis2(with rampart) web service from SoapUI, adding Content-Type: application/soap+xml header didn't work for me, but when I used only Content-Type: application/soap it worked.

Comment: But isn't Axis 2 long outdated? Like from the stone age?