# SOAPUI Mismatch version in Java

Tags: java, soapui

This issue is crazy. I don't understand why its behaving. I guess there should be version issue. When I run the request in SOAPUI tool, it gives me correct response.

But, when I run in my code base by passing the same request object to the same webservice, it says Mismatch version. Any one can help me in cracking this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">    
         <wsa:Action>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</wsa:Action>    
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
         <soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode> 
                        <faultstring>Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI</faultstring><detail/>
         </soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861147/transport-level-information-does-not-match-with-soap-message-namespace-uri) post

Comment: Yes. I had. I tried to give as "application/soap+xml" in content type.. It gives partial correct response.. I mean instead of "<" it shows &lt which is not correct

Comment: Sounds like you need to regenerate the client code

Comment: May be [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1584711) will help

Comment: You can choose if your service support soap 1.1 or 1.2. Please check and use the one supported by your service provider.